# WinAPI function with DirectX

Tags: winapi, directx

I'm very new to win32/DirectX but I'm managing fine with it. I have a really quick question that I don't really understand and it'd be great if someone could clear it up for me. So all the event handlers are calling functions so the DirectX code can can execute stuff when they get executed (like OnMouseDown, OnMouseMove etc).

An example of what I mean is:

```
case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
    OnMouseDown(wParam, GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam));
    return 0;
case WM_RBUTTONUP:
    OnMouseUp(wParam, GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam));
    return 0;
```

So I wanted to do stuff in my DX game when the mouse wheel is scrolled. I searched all over the app for every instance of these functions and copied them to create my own called "OnMouseWheel", but whenever I call this function I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x534D5821 in Init Direct3D.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x534D5821.
```

Whereas if I replace it with one of the other OnMouse functions it works fine, why is this and what do I have to do to fix it?

Right now I have something like this (i've also added my function to the win32 app header and the directX app file):

```
case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
    OnMouseWheel(wParam, GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam));
    return 0;
```

Also I realize that the parameters I've added are probaly not needed for the wheel, I was just copying the other ones, but even if I have a empty function I get the same error.

Header definition:

```
virtual void OnMouseDown(WPARAM btnState, int x, int y){ }
virtual void OnMouseUp(WPARAM btnState, int x, int y)  { }
virtual void OnMouseMove(WPARAM btnState, int x, int y){ }
virtual void OnMouseWheel(WPARAM btnState, int x, int y){ }
virtual void KeyInputTest(){}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for OnMouseWheel?  Also, have you tried a debugger like [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40787)?  It should be able to break in at the access violation so you can see what's causing it.

Comment: Right now there is no code for the OnMouseWheel and I am using visual studio. It breaks the instant it enters the function. It breaks at this line:
return gd3dApp->MsgProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
I'm also trying to make hotkeys too and I get the same issue, whenever I try to make my own function it breaks even though I'm pretty sure I've copied the pre-existing ones exactly the same.

Comment: Have you verified that `gd3dApp` is a valid pointer to your app class? Also, where is OnMouseWheel defined? It's not a standard Win32 API.

Comment: @MooseBoys - Yes it's valid. The OnMouseWheel function was defined in the header of the main file along with the other OnMouse functions. It will jump all the way up to the top of that line and instantly break the moment I step into the new function that was made.

Comment: @user1157885 Can you post the definition then?

Comment: @MooseBoys Yeah sorry for the late response, I didn't notice your message. I added the definitions to my original question.